# When does the difference between a string and a number matter in Perl 5?

Tags: perl, string, numbers

If a string in Perl 5 passes [`looks_like_number`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#looks_like_number-EXPR), it might as well be a number. For instance,

```
my $s = "10" + 5;
```

results in `$s` being assigned `15`.

Are there any cases where a string does not behave like its numeric equivalent would?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When dealing with bitwise operators. `123 ^ 456` is 435, but `"123" ^ "456"` is `"\x05\x07\x05"`. The bitwise operators work numerically if either operand is a number.

Comment: Good point. Interestingly, if either operand is a number, the other operand is treated as a number: `perl -le 'print for "123" ^ 456, 123 ^ "456"'`

Answer (score 11):

I can only think of one: when checking for truth.  Strings that are equivalent to `0`, but that are not `"0"`, such as `"0.0"`, `"0 but true"`, `"0e0"`, etc. all pass `looks_like_number` and evaluate to `0` in numeric context, but are still considered true values.

Answer (score 10):

An equivalent number and string behave differently in hash keys -- or, more generally, any time we stringify a largish number:

```
my (%g, %h);
$g{ 1234000000000000 } = undef;  # '1.234e+015'       => undef
$h{'1234000000000000'} = undef;  # '1234000000000000' => undef
```

Note that we are still within the range where Perl can store the number precisely:

```
> perl -e 'printf qq{%.f\n}, 1234000000000000 + $_ for +1, 0, -1'
1234000000000001
1234000000000000
1233999999999999
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this on any of my systems; `perl -le '$h{1234000000000000} = 0; print keys %h'` spits out 1234000000000000.  Could you post the results of this code on your system: `perl -MDevel::Peek -le '$n = 1234000000000000; $n . ""; Dump $n; print $]'`

Comment: @Chas. I'm running ActivePerl v5.10.0. I get the same behavior with Perl v5.8.8 on a Solaris machine too. Here's the output from your code, run on the Windows box, with semi-colons to indicate line breaks: `SV = PVNV(0x238e4c) at 0x182adb4; REFCNT = 1; FLAGS = (NOK,POK,pNOK,pPOK); IV = 0; NV = 1.234e+015; PV = 0x18351ec "1.234e+015"\0; CUR = 10; LEN = 36; 5.010000`.

Comment: It seems that the machines I tested it on are 64 bit machines and the ones you tested it on are 32 bit machines (or at least 32 bit versions of `perl`).

Comment: That makes sense. Perl stringifies an IV as an integer, and an NV in `printf "%g"` format. On a 32-bit machine, 1234000000000000 lives in the twilight zone where it's too big for an int, but still small enough for exact integer representation as a double, so you don't *notice* it's not an int until you ask it to be a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
  DB<1> sub is_num { my $x = shift; "$x " ~~ $x }

  DB<2> print is_num(123)
1
  DB<3> print is_num('123')

  DB<4>
```